# Creating multiple directories with shell script results in odd directory structure

Tags: bash, ubuntu, mkdir

I wrote a simple bash script to create some directories, like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
PROJECT_DIR=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)
cd ${PROJECT_DIR} || exit 1

mkdir -p Website/{static/{cs,js},templates/{html,xhtml}}
```

However, after I run the script (`./script.sh`), the directory structure looks like this:

[image]

There is no syntax error in my script. When I try the `mkdir` command directly on the terminal, the directories are created correctly.

Why is the bash script run behaving this way?

Comment: Use a `bash` shebang to get `bash` features.

Comment: Just to clarify what @MarkSetchell said: because your script starts with `#!/bin/sh` rather than `#!/bin/bash`, it is apparently executing a non-Bash shell. If you're using bash-specific features, be explicit and always use `#!/bin/bash`. While `/bin/sh` may be bash on some distributions, that's not always the case.

Comment: Paste your script into shellcheck.net it will tell you the problem

Comment: @larsks Even when it's a link to `bash` it disables most extensions.

Comment: @MarkSetchell @larsks Ah I see, I'll make sure to use `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash` next time, thanks! The script now runs correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between sh and Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)